# makefile search device, avrdude

Tags: makefile, avr

I want to program my AVR ATmega644. Therefore I have two programmers. For compiling and programming I using a Makefile, so I only need to type in `make` or `make prog` in a command window and the whole project get's compiled and programmed to the device. This works so far. One programmer is the AVRISPmkII and the other is the Diamex PROG-S. The AVRISPmkII is listened in `/dev/` as an USB device (`/dev/ttyUSB0`) and the Diamex PROG-S as a serial device (`/dev/ttyACM0`). But both are connected via USB. When programming with help of `avrdude` using the AVRISPmkII I have to select the option `-P usb` otherwise the option is `-P /dev/ttyACM0' (compare to my Makefile code below). So I need always to change my Makefile depending on the programmer I use.

Now my question: How can I select the programmer (or avrdude command) automatically depending on the programmer I plugged in? I thought I have to read vendor and product ID of the USB devices to get the device type and then select the command. But what do I have to write into my makefile to do so?

Makefile

```
# Makefile for ATmega644

SRCDIR = src
TMPDIR = tmp
BINDIR = bin
INCDIR = include

mcu = atmega644
SIZE = avr-size
CC = avr-gcc
AS = avr-as
CCFLAGS = -mmcu=$(mcu) -Wall -Os $(addprefix -I, $(INCDIR))
ASMFLAGS = -mmcu=$(mcu) -I $(INCDIR) -Wall

# programmer
#programmer = stk500v2
programmer = avrispmkII
#programmer = avrisp2
partno = m644p
bitclock = 1
port = /dev/ttyACM0
#port = usb

TMP := $(TMPDIR)
OBJECTS = $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.c, $(TMP)/%.o, $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c))
OBJECTS += $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.S, $(TMP)/%.o, $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.S))
TARGET = clock.elf
HEXFILE =$(patsubst %.elf,%.hex,$(TARGET))

all: $(TARGET) $(HEXFILE) 
    $(SIZE) $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $(TARGET)

$(TMP)/%.o:$(SRCDIR)/%.c $(TMP)
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(TMP)/%.o:$(SRCDIR)/%.S $(TMP)
    $(CC) $(ASMFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(TMP):
    mkdir -p $(TMP)

$(HEXFILE): $(TARGET)
    avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom $< $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(TMP)/*
    rm -rf $(TARGET) $(HEXFILE)

.PHONY: prog    
prog:
    avrdude -p $(partno) -B $(bitclock) -P $(port) -c $(programmer) -U flash:w:$(HEXFILE)

.PHONY: fuse
fuse:
    avrdude -p $(partno) -P $(port) -c $(programmer) -U lfuse:w:0xe2:m -U hfuse:w:0xd9:m

.PHONY: read_fuse
read_fuse:
    avrdude -p $(partno) -P $(port) -c $(programmer) -U lfuse:r:-:i -U hfuse:r:-:i

.PHONY: debug
debug:
    avr-objdump -dS $(TARGET)

.PHONY: reset
reset:
    avrdude -p $(partno) -P $(port) -c $(programmer)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `/dev/ttyACM0` does not exist then `$(wildcard /dev/ttyACM0)` will evaluate to an empty string:

```
ifeq($(wildcard /dev/ttyUSB0),)
    port = /dev/ttyACM0
    programmer = stk500v2
else
    port = usb
    programmer = avrispmkII
```

Please note that with this code, any file listenend as `/dev/ttyUSB0` will make the port be usb and the programmer avrispmkII.